# Ruby: "String can't be coerced into Fixnum" when printing a Hash pair

Tags: ruby

I just started learning Ruby yesterday, at Codeacademy, and while in Data Structures part of the course, I tried the following:

```
my_hash = {1=>2,3=>4,"5"=>"6"}
my_hash[7] = my_hash[1]+my_hash[3]
my_hash.each { |k,v|
# Here I want to print key and values like "Key: Value"
}
```

In line 4,

This works:

```
puts "#{k}: #{v}"
```

This doesn't:

```
puts k+": "+v
```

I get `String can't be coerced into Fixnum`.
Why? I'm just printing the dictionary keys and values. I'm not typecasting anything into anything other. What's the problem?

Comment: Because the k, v of your first hash is 1 => 2, means that k, v class is a Fixnum so cannot add with ": " which is a string, ruby don't accept that. 
I think using `"#{k}: #{v}"` is the best solution, or you can use `k.to_s + ": " + v.to_s` instead of.

Comment: Yeah! I just did that ===>  `puts k.to_s+": "+v.to_s`

I guess in Ruby `+` doesn't mean concatenation if a number is used with it in the print statement.

Comment: That's right! And one more thing: `to_s` is method of `Class` class, so every variable have that function, even `nil`, so feel free to use it

Comment: Thanks.. Just my Java-ish brain got confused I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Corrected following Chuck's comment.

The problem is indeed that you are not typecasting. In the first iteration, you pass `k` the value `1`, which is a fixnum. In order to do `+` on `1`, the argument to `+` also has to be a numeral, but you gave `": "`, which is a string. That is what you are doing wrong. If you want to do `+` as string, you have to do typecasting on `1` such as by doing `1.to_s` (which is what `"#{1}"` is doing in your first version).

Comment: Tiny nitpick: The argument can be any of the standard Numeric types. It could be a Fixnum, Float, Rational, BigDecimal, etc.